# Data not binding in the angular dropdown

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

> I have created a dropdown using angularjs and bootstrap.
>   i want to open a link if it clicks any value from the the dropdown.
>   But not able to get the data in the dropdownlist.
>   Below is the fiddle link.help is much appreciated:-

Code goes here:-

> HTML Code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
 <div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-    toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
 <span class="caret"></span></button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-repeat="item in items">
<li><a href="">{{item.GroupName}}</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

> Controller

```
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.controller("myController",['$scope',function($scope){
$scope.items=[{"GroupID":"15","GroupName":"Client Management Product"},
             {"GroupID":"5","GroupName":"DevOps"},
             {"GroupID":"18","GroupName":"Resource Centre"},
             {"GroupID":"16","GroupName":"SEF"},
             {"GroupID":"17","GroupName":"Shared Services"}]
}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smsh/st4hn14a/

Comment: Example of such dropdowns are here:http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi you have not added boootstrap.min.js and jQuery as external resources in your example

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uslperera/st4hn14a/8/)

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items"><a href="">{{item.GroupName}}</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use these two, just use angularstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and that should do the trick for both libs.

Comment: Actually i have added the jquery and bootstrap.js in my actual code but forgot to add in my fiddle.Now i am able to do it when i tried in my actual code